Moderator Election - Community Interest Check
We last had a moderator election back in late 2018, and we have had a moderator step down since then, so currently we are running with just 2 - Maarten and myself. Now, the good thing is that generally this site runs without too much moderator involvement - so we're not too overloaded.
That said, this is an opportunity to have an election. Having a third moderator would be beneficial either to diversify our availability coverage beyond "standard sleep schedule on CET" or to handle day-to-day business better should both Maarten and I be low on time on a particular day / week. Also it would probably reduce flag handling latency as we commonly discuss more difficult situations to find a good solution.
To avoid finding ourselves in a situation where an election would fail* due to an insufficient number of candidates, though, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, when the actual election's nomination period starts.
Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.
NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination. In particular you're not binding yourself by answering nor do you need to provide actual reasons right now for why people should vote for you in particular.
Credit: This question used Rory Alsop's similar check as a template.
*: You may be wondering why this is a concern: SE only has a limited amount of slots for concurrent elections and taking one just for the election to fail wouldn't be nice to other sites. Also we would waste time on the question collection and answering part that is done by nominees.

I would apply if there were elections right now.

I would as well.  Academic have a habit of being impartial, but sadly busy. :/

Ping ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$
